# 'duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64' when updating Firebase Messaging

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-toolbox-for-mac

My iOS app uses Firebase Messaging and Google Toolbox for Mac (GTM). GTM was previously included in the project directly with files (ie. not cocoapods). However when installing Firebase Messaging via pods, it also installs GTM with pods because it is a dependency - therefore I have two copies of GTM in my project.

This is the error that occurs when building this project in Xcode:

```
147 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I use the GTM added with pods over the GTM that was added directly with files?

Comment: have you tried removing all_load in build settings. got duplicated symbols in my other project because of another framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either eliminate the separate copy of GTM or use [Firebase without CocoaPods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks).